# Cookie issue after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have used cookies for remember login. It is working fine in localhost. But after hosting to the server am trying to access through url. This time it is not working. But I can see the cookie value using firebug.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: May,after hosting,you forgot change cookie domain

Comment: It would help if you provided some code to look at.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382590/session-timeout-owin-in-mvc-4-after-5-minutes

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. The problem was with the URL case. Cookieee is case sensitive because of that this problem happens. NowI have fixed this issue.